# How to get the list of secondary partitions of a database for a composite partition in DolphinDB

Tags: sql, database, distributed-computing, dolphindb

I have the following database,

```
    m = "tag" + string(decimalFormat(1..1000,'0000'))
    tableSchema = table(100:0,`devID`ts join m ,[INT,DATETIME] join take(FLOAT,1000) )
    db1 = database("",VALUE,2019.01M..2020.12M)
    db2 = database("",RANGE,0..10*10+1)
    db = database(dbName,COMPO,[db1,db2])
    dfsTable = db.createPartitionedTable(tableSchema,tableName,`ts`devID)
```

Is there any function that can get the list of second-level partitions？

Answer (score 0):

schema(table|dbHandle)).partitionSchema[1]